# Need to load .env file before any init function is run

Tags: go

I'm trying to load the environment variable with calling `godotenv.Load` in my `main` method but the problem is that I have `init` functions in other packages and they run before the environment variables are loaded from .env file, therefore causing trouble.

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: There is an obvious workaround: do not load .env files by programs which are supposed to use the environment variables set by such files. If you note that environment variables as a form of configuration was actually invented to affect the behaviour of the programs, and hence such variables were to set up before a program using them runs. Trying to set environment variables in a running process has no sense: you could just as well tweak internal program's variables.

Comment: Sure, there's another workaround: initialize the environment variables and then re-execute the program so that it sees them when it's run. But this design is very broken due to the reasons already explained.

Comment: @kostix Fair point, but still there is an issue with `envconfig` that initializes a struct based on the environment variables.

Are these modules all redundant? It seems then the only option is `os.Getenv`

Comment: What is `envconfig`? I do not quite get what you're asking for.

Comment: Ah, you mean `github.com/kelseyhightower/envconfig`? If yes, I still don't get what you're asking for. `envconfig` is a tool for "mass-application" of the values of environment variables to fields of structs—nothing more; that is, it can spare you writing a bit of boilerplate code and internally it surely calls `os.Getenv` or the like. But this is not concerned with how these environment variables are set because env. vars are supposed to be set _before_ a program which reads them actually starts.

Comment: I mean, if you've written a program which uses `envconfig` to initialize internal program state from environment variables and then use another package (`godotenv`?) to initialize environment variables whose names and values are read from a text file, this means you've invended a configuration system which involves a whole unneeded layer: environment variables—simply because initializing internal state _directly_ from the data read from a file is a much more sensible thing to do.

Comment: While we are at it, please note that it's technically impossible in Go to run code before the `init` statements are executed as they are defined to run before `main`, and whichever of them runs before the others is only determined by the dependencies of the packages they are defined in (`init`s in dependencies run before `init`s in the packages which use them), but IIRC that's the only thing defined about this ordering.

Comment: In other words, do not depend on `init`s to initialize the state of your program. This must be a clearly defined step somewhere early in `main`, which must be allowed to fail gracefully, and make the program exit with an error message and a non-zero exit code.

Comment: @kostix — There are good reasons for setting environment variable within your [running] program, such as, for instance, setting the environment inherited by any child processes your program spawns.

Comment: @kostix I just gave up on the `envconfig` part and now I set the environment variables before running the app, but still not sure where else you're supposed to use `godotenv` if not before anything else.

Comment: I think I still failed to get my point across despite two attempts ;-) It's _fine_ to use `gototenv` or whatever else package to initialize internal program state from values contained in environment variables. But 1) this approach _supposes_ some other code sets this variables up. As soon as the same app tries to first set a bunch of environment variables from a textual config file in order to immediately read values from these variables back to initialize its internal state, I call this overengineering: because it looks like "text config → env. vars → internal state"…

Comment: …instead of "text config → internal state". 2) It completely misses me why you need to do all this stuff "before `init`s are run. If there are `init` functions in your own code which want to rely on some already initialized state to run correctly, refactor this code because it contains a design flaw. If it's some third-party package—report a bug, and then maybe you have a valid reason for such workaround. If, instead, you desgined the code this way, I claim this design is bad: make initialization a clearly separated step which runs _from `main`_ before any other code.

Comment: Makes sense, I clearly have some logic in some `init` functions which are not supposed to be there, thanks for your help.

Comment: By the way, I beleive I've witnessed someone from the Go core team to express regret about adding `init` feature in the first place ;-) While generally useful, it's able to create subtle problems; in most cases where it's useful, it could be replaced by initializing and carrying around explicit variables, and in the cases where that would be not convenient, a policy could be implemented for packages to export dedicated functions to initialize their state, and ways to implement this.

Comment: Sure, the latter would complicate the life of package writers as they would need often (if not always) to resort fo using `sync.Once`, but still these drawbacks would not be fatal. OK, anyway, Go 1.x is what it is and `init`s are not bad, just have limited use cases.

Comment: Thanks for the details. Unfortunately, these conventions make the code harder to read and maintain, so totally agree.

I think the modules I was using to load environment variables are better suited for projects like CLIs or some scripts without much complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the spec for Golang's package initialization: https://go.dev/ref/spec#Package_initialization

In a nutshell, for a given package,

1. All packages imported by the current package are initialized in lexical order by source file name and then in the order in which they are imported in each source file.
2. All package-level variables in the current package are initialized in dependency order.
3. All `init()` functions defined within the current package are then executed in lexical order by source file name, and then in document order within each file.
4. Once all packages have been initialized, the `main()` function is invoked, starting execution of the program.

Per the spec,

> Package initialization—variable initialization and the invocation of init functions—happens in a single goroutine, sequentially, one package at a time.

All you need to do is ensure that your loading/setting of environment variable happens in a package that gets initialized first. **Note however** that `go fmt` will alphabetize your `imports`.

So, given a program with 4 packages, `main`, `alpha`, `bravo`, and `charlie`,

where the dependencies are:

- `main` imports `alpha` and `bravo`, and
- `alpha` imports `charlie`

and each package has multiple `init()` functions (source code below),
executing `go run main.go` writes the following to the console:

```
charlie/main.go: init: 1
charlie/main.go: init: 2
charlie/main.go: init: 3
alpha/main.go: init: 1
alpha/main.go: init: 2
alpha/main.go: init: 3
bravo/main.go: init: 1
bravo/main.go: init: 2
bravo/main-.go: init: 3
main.go: init: 1
main.go: init: 2
main.go: init: 3
main(): executing
```

#### `./main.go`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "some-host/init-example/alpha"
    "some-host/init-example/bravo"
)

func init() {
    fmt.Println("main.go: init: 1")
}

func init() {
    fmt.Println("main.go: init: 2")
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("main(): executing")
    alpha.DoSomething()
    bravo.DoSomething()
}

func init() {
    fmt.Println("main.go: init: 3")
}
```

#### `./alpha/alpha.go`

```
package alpha

import (
    "fmt"
    "some-host/init-example/charlie"
)

func init() {
    fmt.Println("alpha/main.go: init: 1")
}

func init() {
    fmt.Println("alpha/main.go: init: 2")
}

func DoSomething() {
    charlie.DoSomething()
}

func init() {
    fmt.Println("alpha/main.go: init: 3")
}
```

#### `./bravo/bravo.go`

```
package bravo

import "fmt"

func init() {
    fmt.Println("bravo/main.go: init: 1")
}

func init() {
    fmt.Println("bravo/main.go: init: 2")
}

func DoSomething() {
}

func init() {
    fmt.Println("bravo/main-.go: init: 3")
}
```

#### `./charlie/charlie.go`

```
package charlie

import "fmt"

func init() {
    fmt.Println("charlie/main.go: init: 1")
}

func init() {
    fmt.Println("charlie/main.go: init: 2")
}

func DoSomething() {
}

func init() {
    fmt.Println("charlie/main.go: init: 3")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've read about the precedence of package initialization but I was thinking perhaps there is an idiomatic way to load variables from .env file into structs in Go.

To my surprise apparently there is none. Using alphabetic ordering is really unreliable and even myself won't remember it after a few months and the application will break.